# A graphing calculator

Tags: python, performance, graph, calculator, matplotlib

I wrote a calculator that can solve equations with variables using matplotlib and sympy.
I am looking for tips on performance and style.
How can I improve on this calculator? Is it a good idea to use sympy for this purpose?
[Repl.it](https://repl.it/talk/share/Introducing-msh-A-graphing-shell/55694)

```
import sympy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
class Iterator:
  name, equation, val = None, None, None
  def __repr__(self):
    return self.__str__()
  def __init__(self, nameIn, equationIn, valIn):
    self.name, self.equation, self.val = nameIn, equationIn, valIn
  def __str__(self):
    return self.get_name() + "," + str(self.get_value())
  def iterate(self):
    replaced = self.equation.replace(self.name, str(self.val))
    self.val = sympy.sympify(replaced)
  def get_name(self):
    return self.name
  def get_value(self):
    return self.val
def graph():
  numTimes = input("How many points ")
  x = input("What to calculate ")
  points = []
  i = 0
  numInputs = int(input("How many variables "))
  j = 0
  replaced = []
  iterators = []
  while numInputs > j:
    name = input("What's the variabe name ")
    iter = input("What's the iteration equation ")
    val = int(input("What's the starting value "))
    iterators.append(Iterator(name, iter, val))
    j += 1
  while i < int(numTimes):
    replaced = x.replace("n", str(i))
    for j in iterators:
      replaced = replaced.replace(j.get_name(), str(j.get_value()))
      j.iterate()
    final = sympy.sympify(replaced)
    right_type = int(final)
    points.append(right_type)
    i += 1
  plt.plot(points)
  plt.ylabel(input("What's the y label "))
  plt.show()
while(True):
  command = input(">> ")
  if command == "graph":
    graph()
  elif command == "help":
    print("""
    msh.
    Used for graphing.
    Commands:
    graph: an interactive graphing calculator
    help: bring up this message
    quit: exit msh
    """)
  elif command == "quit":
    break
```

Comment: In Python, indentation is important. Please fix your indentation. Why did you create a class if it's basically an initialisation and one big function after that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Indentation

You should use four spaces instead of two.

## Spacing

Your class methods should be separated by an empty line, so everything doesn't look so crowded.

## Getters

Since all class variables are public (except `_var` and `__var` variables), you don't need to define getters to access these properties. Simple do `Iterator.name`, etc.

## `Iterator.__str__`

You should utilize `f""` strings to directly include variables in strings.

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name},{self.val}"
```

Comment: But doesn't it make sense to make all variables "private" (__var or at least _var) and provide setters and getters with @property?

Comment: @TomGebel Not really. There's no structural advantage to making something private (which isn't enforced in Python anyway) and then offering for anyone to set it to anything; public accomplishes the same thing and is more Python-idiomatic.